# Compare JavaScript Object-Array Property with String

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, compare

Hello I have a quick question regarding my javascript array:

```
var firstrecord = {
    name: 'Luca',
    age: '19'
};
var secondrecord = {
    name: 'Hans',
    age: '25'
}

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(firstrecord,secondrecord);
```

Alright, now I have a `var SearchString = "Lu"`.

What I'd do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].[name].IndexOf(SearchString, i)) != 1){
    return myArray[i];
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any solution to this problem ?

Update: indexOf != IndexOf
Reminder to self.. first lookup the use of such functions before misusing them. :)

Comment: It's stylistically unorthodox to use a leading upper-case letter for the names of simple variables. Generally upper-case is reserved for constructor function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two errors here:

```
if (myArray[i].[name].IndexOf(SearchString, i)) != 1){
```

First, it's `.indexOf()`, lower-case "i".  Second, you need just one or the other of `.` and `[ ]`:

```
if (myArray[i].name.indexOf(SearchString, i)) != 1)
```

Now, I don't know what it is you're trying to do here, but passing `i` as the second parameter of `.indexOf()` doesn't make much sense to me, and neither does comparing the return value to `1`. If what you want to do is see if the search text appears at the start of the name, you'd do this:

```
if (myArray[i].name.indexOf(SearchString) == 0)
```

Comment: That was fast! You got me, where I'm passing the i, that was not correct, got that from another try. Your solution works like a charm :)